# How to loop and compare pairs of lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, file-handling

I have 2 files like this.

File 1

```
e 1 0 ppp
e 3 1 rrr
e 3 2 rrr
```

File 2

```
e 1 0 rrr
```

I want to split each line of code to compare array[3] it should print `OK` if same rrr in line. I write code like this.

```
file1 = open('file1.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8")
file2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')

for line1 in file1:     #loop file1

    L1 = line1.split()   #split to array

    if(L1[0] == 'e'):
        print("line1 " + line1)

        for line2 in file2:  #loop file2

            L2 = line2.split()   #split to array

            if(L2[0] == 'e'):
                print("line2 " + line2)

                if(L2[3] == L1[3]):  #check rrr same

                    print("OK")
```

when I run the code it prints this:

```
line1 e 1 0 ppp
line2 e 1 0 rrr
line1 e 3 1 rrr
line1 e 3 2 rrr
```

The code is loop in loop I want to show result like this:

```
line1 e 1 0 ppp
line2 e 1 0 rrr
line1 e 3 1 rrr
line2 e 1 0 rrr
line1 e 3 2 rrr
line2 e 1 0 rrr
```

How to modify code to compare each line of the file?

Comment: file object iterators are only good for one pass. I believe that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to keep track of the last line from both files. incase if any of the file is smaller and finishes iteration before the other one.
you need to compare the current line with previous line from the other file.

how about this?

```
prev_f1_token = None
prev_f1_line = None

prev_f2_token = None
prev_f2_line = None

with open('file1.txt') as f1:
    with open('file2.txt') as f2:
        for line in f1:
            prev_f1_token = line[0]
            prev_f1_line = line
            for line in f2:
                prev_f2_token = line[0]
                prev_f2_line = line

            if(prev_f1_token == 'e'):
                print("line1 ", prev_f1_line)

            if (prev_f2_token == 'e'):
                print ("line2 ", prev_f2_line)

                if(prev_f2_line.split()[3] == prev_f1_line.split()[3]):  #check rrr same
                        print("OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing way much code than it is required and its not always a good idea to continue if your code is getting that much indented. This is my attempt to print what you want and I'm sure this can be shortened more!

You can use `itertools.cycle` here *(it returns a cyclic iterator in case of a shorter list)*

```
import itertools
f1, f2 = open('file1.txt', 'r'), open('file2.txt', 'r')
file1, file2 = f1.read().split(), f2.read().split()
if len(file1) > len(file2):
    file2 = itertools.cycle(file2)
else:
    file1 = itertools.cycle(file1)  
print '\n'.join(['line1 '+i+'\nline2 '+j for i,j in zip(file1, file2)])
f1.close();f2.close()
```